# Api Platform Softdeleteable extension does not filter deleted entities but sets the removal date correctly

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Api platform (Symfony 4).

Despite removing an entity, this entity still appears in the listings but deleted_at field in database is setted correctly.
Listener run well but the filter seems not to work.

Config:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            timestampable: true
            loggable: true
            softdeleteable: true
```

---

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        [...]
        gedmo_loggable:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
            is_bundle: false
            alias: Gedmo
        gedmo_tree:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
            is_bundle: false
            alias: Tree
    filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true
```

---

```
resources:
    App\Entity\Folder:
        attributes:
            pagination_enabled: false
        itemOperations:
            delete: ~
            put: ~
            get: ~
        collectionOperations:
            get: 
                filters: ['catalogue.order_filter']
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", hardDelete=false)
 */
class Folder extends Catalogue implements ParentCatalogueAware, ChildCatalogueAware
{
```